# A question about the mean value inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was trying to remember results about advanced calculus and I've noticed that some authors state the mean value inequality in a slightly way. I know this result as follow:

" If $f:U \longrightarrow V$ is a diferentiable function from an open subset $U$ of $\mathcal{R}^n$ into a Banach Space $V$ such that $\| f'(x) \| \leq M$, for some $M>0$ and all $x \in U$, and $[y,x]\subset U$, then 
$$\| f(y)-f(x) \| \leq \|y-x\| M.$$

In "The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operator", vol. 1, the first theorem proved by Hormander is a version of the same theorem. We will denote by $I$ an open interval of the real line and by $V$ a Banach space. If $f:I\longrightarrow V$ is differentiable (not necessarily a $C^1$ function) in $I$, then

$$\| f(y)-f(x) \| \leq \|y-x\| \sup \left\{ \|f'(x+t(y-x)) \| : 0\leq t\leq 1 \right\}.$$

He starts the proof considering $M> \sup \left\{ \|f'(x+t(y-x)) \| : 0\leq t\leq 1 \right\}$. I can't see why this supremum is a finite number if we just know that the function is differentiable (and it have to be finite, otherwise he can't take such M). Since I've found in many texts the firts version of the theorem, I was wondering if the situation $n=1$ is fundamental. So, my doubt is:

1) Why the supremum is finite?
2) Can we generalize the first statement (that $M$ always exist)?

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistakes, it's my first time here. I will edit as soon as a I see a mistake.

Comment: Your first sentence says $\|f'(x)\| \le M$. Does that mean at a specific point or throughout $U$?

Comment: It's for all $x$. I will edit. Thank you!

Comment: If the $\sup$ isn't finite then the inequality is saying $$\| f(x)-f(y)\| \leq \infty,$$ which is always true (and useless).

Comment: So is he considering that the supremum can be infinite? I was afraid that this was the answer. Do you know any example?

Comment: Take for instance $f(t)= t^2\sin(1/t^2)$ in an interval around $0$, and choose $x<0<y$.

Comment: It works!! Thank you.